# Build Configurations for Git Flow

Tags: git, teamcity, build-automation, git-flow

How are people setting up their build configurations when using Git and Git-flow?  I have several tasks I want to complete:

- Commit - compile, run static code analysis, unit test, package
- Integration Test - run integration tests
- Deploy to Test - deploy the app to a test environment
- Functional Test - run end-to-end functional tests
- Deploy to QA - manual pull into a QA environment that runs smoke tests

With master, develop, release feature branches I'm curious how people map them into the build processes.

Answer (score 2):

We currently have

- **CI Build**

  - The VCS Root has a branch specification that includes develop, feature/*, release/*, hotfix/* and master
  - A VCS commit trigger for all branches
  - Pull request build feature branches and link build results and approve
  - Auto-merge master -> develop
- **Release notes build**

  - A snapshot on CI Build
  - Generates release notes from commits and commits it
- **Deploy to Dev Build**

  - A snapshot on CI Build
  - Scheduled to deploy twice a day
  - Only develop branch is deployed
- **Deploy to UAT Build**

  - Manual step
  - A snapshot on CI Build
  - Only release/*, hotfix/* or master can be deployed to UAT
- **Deploy to Prod**

  - Manual step
  - A snapshot on Deploy to UAT Build
  - Only master can be deployed here (when release or hoftix is closed master needs to be deployed to UAT first for smoke testing)

Teamcity auto-merge doesn't allow for wildcards, so we are working on our own method to keep branches in sync

- master -> develop, release/*, hotfix/*
- develop -> feature/*

Comment: I like the process you explained in your answer. The only part I don't understand is "Deployment to UAT Build" when you auto-merge master -> develop. Why would I do that if the build has been made from a release or hotfix branch? Don't you want to use gitflow's finish hotfix/release when "Deploy to Prod" is complete to make sure that production is in sync with master branch?

Comment: @AliB thanks that is in the wrong spot. It's actually part of the CI build for master branch i.e. when a hotfix or release is closed and merged. I've  updated my answer

Comment: @JohSquared, I still think you need to merge master to develop when you are in Deploy to Prod Build config. master branch needs to be a mirror code of what you have in production and if you merge it earlier, your master branch and Prod would go out of sync. Creating hotfixes become an issue when you need it.

Comment: @AliB You should sync master to develop, as soon as a commit comes into master, in the case of GitFlow that is when a Release or Hotfix are closed. In my case, when a commit is made on any branch the CI build is triggered. So for example when a release is tested and ready for prod. release is closed and merged into master -> CI Build on master is triggered  -> on success master merges to develop -> Deploy to UAT Build is run for master (quick smoke test) -> Deploy to Prod build is run

Answer (score 0):

This is my workflow:

[Branch-per-Feature (dymitruk.com)](http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/)

it's adapted from nvie's